# Big memory consumption during wcf file transfer

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP) and although the transfering method is streamed once I hit upload the ram consumption on the client jumps to 1GB. After the transfer is finished the memory isn't reduced. My code is below:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
{                 
    if (File.Exists(openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        //System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        FileTransferServiceReference.ITransferService clientUpload = new FileTransferServiceReference.TransferServiceClient();
        FileTransferServiceReference.RemoteFileInfo uploadRequestInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();

         uploadRequestInfo.FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
         uploadRequestInfo.Length = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName).Length;
         uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = File.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName);
         clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo);
     }
        }
```

on the App.config there is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
   </startup>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://62.1.193.176/transferTEST/wcfTest.TransferService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService"
            contract="FileTransferServiceReference.ITransferService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why aren't you closing the service client clientUpload.Close()and uploadRequestInfo.Close()?

Comment: I assume you see that behavior due to the arrays that are created for each blockread while streaming. I see you are disposing this stream but is your clientUpload also disposing?

Comment: This is no `.close()` method on my `clientUpload`.

Comment: I changed my `clientUpload` to `TransferServiceClient` type and I removed the `uploadRequestInfo`. Added an `clientUpload.close()` and still nothing.

Comment: Also you may need to close uploadRequestInfo  as the File stream assignment is done on this object.

Comment: I updated my code. Still jumps to 1GB, my file is not 1GB.

Comment: You should dispose `new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)` this after upload is completed

Comment: I put it in a `using` statement still nothing.

Comment: Have you properly configured `transferMode` as `Streamed` for both client and service?

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated my code, this time I added my App.config

Comment: @George Take a look at the example - Implementation: Web Server section - web.config (since it's using a web client). You need to do something similar in your app.config. At least add `transferMode="Streamed"` for your `binding`